# Update DateTime into sql db throws

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, insert

I am trying to update a DateTime object into a datetime field of a sql (SQL Server 2000) database.

I have the following function

```
Public Sub Update(ByVal lastlogin as DateTime)

Using slqupdate as SqlCommand = _connection.CreateCommand()
  sqlupdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
  sqlupdate.CommandText = "UPDATE myTable SET LastLogin = @lastlogin WHERE ID = 2"

  updatelastlogin = sqlupdate.CreateParameter()
  updatelastlogin.ParameterName = "@lastlogin"
  updatelastlogin.DbType = SqlDbType.DateTime
  updatelastlogin.Value = lastlogin
  slqlupdate.Parameters.Add(updatelastlogin)

  sqlupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()    
End Using
End Sub
```

Attempting to call it as follows Update(DateTime.Now) produces the following Exception:

> Failed to convert parameter value from
>   a DateTime to a Decimal.

I am not sure what I've done wrong, does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try SQLDBType instead of DBType

Comment: No problem. I found the problem quickly when I ported your sample to c#.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the Microsoft MSDN:

```
Private Sub UpdateDemographics(ByVal customerID As Integer, _
    ByVal demoXml As String, _
    ByVal connectionString As String)

    ' Update the demographics for a store, which is stored 
    ' in an xml column.
    Dim commandText As String = _
     "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics " _
     & "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandText, connection)

        ' Add CustomerID parameter for WHERE clause.
        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
        command.Parameters("@ID").Value = customerID

        ' Use AddWithValue to assign Demographics.
        ' SQL Server will implicitly convert strings into XML.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml)

        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim rowsAffected As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

The "command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)" part should be an option, stating that it is a datetime parameter?